# Ejecutar un evento al insertar un registro en mysql

Tags: sql, nodejs, linux, mysqli

Hola necesito crear una especie de monitor de una tabla del Mysql, donde cuando se ingrese un registro ejecute un js o un php. La aplicacion que le daria es para enviar mails donde cada registro seria un mail a enviar entonces cuando se ingresa un registro este tendria la info necesaria para enviarlo y luego borrar ese registro. Mi mayor problema es como ejecutar la tarea cuando se ingresa un registro.

Comment: aja.. y el problema cual es?

Comment: Por lo que entendí te puede servir crear un `TRIGGER` luego de insertar nuevo registro en el tabla, que te retorne algún valor y puedas ejecutar la tarea desde el fronted.